# Chat application. What should be the end of message character

Tags: java, chat, livechat

I am creating a chat application in Java. User can send multiple new lines in a single message. Previously, I was not allowing the user to send new lines. So it was easy to use new line character as End OF Message. But now I am allowing the user to send new lines in a message. What character/string should I use to mark the end of the message.

Comment: The [`EOF`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0003/index.htm) character seems like a very nice choice.

Comment: A NUL character ('\0') looks like a good candidate. Better still if you can change the protocol to send the length of the input followed by the actual bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily avoid end of message by adding extra 4 byte. First 4 byte represent length of your message. Then add full message.

Sample sender code:

```
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    String msg = "its a test message";
    byte[] byteMsg = msg.getBytes();

    int length = byteMsg.length;
    byte[] lengthByte = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(length).array();

    byte[] finalMsg = new byte[length+4];
    System.arraycopy(lengthByte, 0, finalMsg, 0, 4);
    System.arraycopy(byteMsg, 0, finalMsg, 4, length);

    bufferedOutputStream.write(finalMsg);
```

When you read your message then read first 4 byte. Convert this 4 byte to integer. This is your incoming message length. Then parse those byte.

Answer (score 0):

It's your application so you're free to use whatever you like, including `EOF` and `NUL` characters suggested by Marko and KDM.

Just make sure it's a character your users won't be using in their messages.

Comment: Downvoter please explain the reason of downvote. As I'm going to use this method in my simple application. I'll use a bit more advanced method such as specifying message length in message, once the demo is passed.